# Setting border around custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want to put a custom button as right navigation bar button item. Here is the code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(filterResult) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

The problem is that I can see only the image and not the button around it like it comes for UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd or other types.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

replaces the entire image for the specified state. You have to draw the full own image and not only the icon on it (or whatever you want).