# iPhone SDK: UIBarButtonItem is not displaying border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIToolbar which I am trying to put some custom UIBarButtonItems on. However, when I use the code below, the button shows up with **NO** border.

```
    UIImage *cameraRollButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flash.png"];
    UIButton *cameraRollButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cameraRollButton setImage:cameraRollButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cameraRollButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cameraRollButtonImage.size.width, cameraRollButtonImage.size.height);

    // Initialize the UIBarButtonItem
    cameraRollButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cameraRollButton];
    [cameraRollButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

    //Add the Buttons to the toolbar
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cameraRollButtonItem];
    [self.cameraTabBar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

This displays the button just fine, however, there is NO button border (like standard the `UIBarButtonItem`). So the line `[cameraRollButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];` doesn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I would like to be able to eventually rotate the image in the button when the device orientation is changed (keeping the toolbar static), so simply adding an image to the `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't work; I need to get this to work with by using the `customView` property.

Many thanks!
Brett

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020267/setting-border-around-custom-uibarbuttonitem ?

Comment: @Da_smokes: I saw that one. It has virtually the same code as in this question, but the answer is to switch the image. Which isn't what I need. That code does not display a border either. Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: Looks like you are assigning a custom button to it but then you also want to give that button a style therefore trying to overide the custom button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating your own button image with a border? You can use it as the `backgroundImage` of a `UIButton`:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setBackgroundImage:_backgroundImage_ forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// So that the button does not gray out when disabled
[button setBackgroundImage:_backgroundImage_ forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; 

[button setImage:_cameraImage_ forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 30);
```

You could then use `button` with `initWithCustomView:`.

The PSD file [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/) might give you an overview of how to create your own button.